# Byobu status bar not showing updates in PuTTY since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, putty, byobu

When I was running Ubuntu 11.10, I had byobu configured to show different status messages at the bottom of the screen. This worked just fine while I was in PuTTY. I upgraded to 12.04 today, though, and now I have this:

[image]

the region highlighted in red was where the status bar would have been. Here's what I have done so far:

- Changed byobu's backend from tmux to screen
- Deleted ~/.screenrc and ~/.byobu/
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure byobu
- uninstalled/reinstalled byobu

I'm kind of out of ideas here. It was really handy having this status bar, as I only access my Ubuntu box via PuTTY.

Comment: Incidentally, after upgrading my system (and the screen), it appears to have fixed itself. I'm wondering if it was a bug...

Answer (score 1):

if there is a "status.disable" file in your byobu config dir, remove it.

Or, in sh parlance :

```
rm $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/status.disable
```

Also, there may be several tmux-x lines defined in the `$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/status` config file, try

```
SHIFT+F5
```

To cycle them.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my custom status bar disappeared. I believe it's because the syntax of `~/.byobu/status` has changed.

It used to be something like

```
arch=0
battery=0
cpu_count=0
cpu_freq=0
...
```

Now it's like

```
screen_upper_left="color"
screen_upper_right="color whoami hostname ip_address menu"
screen_lower_left="color logo distro release #arch"
```

I haven't verified that yet but I'll see if that fixes my problem...